# replace sql view in a safe way under db load

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I want to to find out a working mechanism to have version tables in mysql, such as a heavy loaded app can use sql queries to version table in a sql-view manner i.e. it should be an sql-query without real version number (usually, it should be `max_version-1` , because `max_version` is being populated by data), and the most important thing that the mechanism must use a safe way to switch to a next version of table under heavy load.

Is it safe to use `create or replace view` for such a task?
Is there any other solutions to achieve this?
Is there any other pitfalls to do so under heavy load?

Comment: How often are versions changing?  Is one row versioned at a time?  Or is the whole table replaced?  Is a version number associated with each row?  Or some periodic "release"?

Comment: Whole table has a version number. And it replaces at a single moment .

Answer (score 0):

Instantaneous, no-downtime table swap:

```
CREATE TABLE new LIKE real;
load `new` by whatever means you like
RENAME TABLE real TO old, new TO real;
DROP TABLE old;  -- or keep as the "old version".
```

You can probably use that as an important part of your versioning.